# How to create a folder in Sharepoint using Java and RESTFul API?

Tags: sharepoint-server, web-services, rest, java-api

This is my Sharepoint site `http://sp2k13/sites/ifsp/` and I would like to create a folder using Sharepoint RESTFul API with Java.

I have already gone through [Working with folders and files with REST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn292553.aspx) in sharepoint msdn.

But how to do it with Java? I think it will be possible.

Comment: Do you want to create folders in document library or lists?

Comment: @AsadRefai in lists

Comment: You need only REST solution or JavaScript Object Model is fine with you?

Comment: @AsadRefai I am asking for REST solution

Comment: In my experience, creating Folders using REST does not work correctly. When you create a Folder in SharePoint it actually creates the Folder and an associated List Item. It's the List Item that shows in the List View in the SharePoint UI. When you create a Folder using the REST API, it just creates the Folder. I've reported this issue on the Office 365 Dev User Voice.

Comment: You may want to consider using a workflow to create the folders. It is a much easier solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something similar as below

```
String req = "http://sp2k13/sites/ifsp/_api/Web/Folders/add('LibraryName/FolderName')"
NTCredentials credentials = new NTCredentials(UserName, Password, "JAVA-MACHINE-NAME", "DOMAIN");
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.getState().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, credentials);
httpClient.getParams().setAuthenticationPreemptive(true);

ClientExecutor clientExecutor = new ApacheHttpClientExecutor(httpClient);
java.net.URI uri = new java.net.URI(req);
ClientRequestFactory fac = new ClientRequestFactory(clientExecutor, uri);

ClientRequest request = fac.createRequest(req);
request.header("content-type", "application/json;odata=verbose");
request.header("X-RequestDigest", digestValue);
request.accept("application/json;odata=verbose");

ClientResponse<String> response = request.post(String.class);

if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " +
        response.getStatus());
}
```

For more information go through article http://blog.ctp.com/2012/12/21/interoperability-between-java-and-sharepoint-2013-on-premises/

Answer (score 0):

JShare uses REST protocol to access to SharePoint and Office 365.

Check this [create folder example](http://www.independentsoft.de/jshare/tutorial/createfolder.html)

Answer (score 0):

I found on the net Jshare. It's Java API for Microsoft SharePoint  from [Independentsoft company](http://www.independentsoft.de). There is an example of creating a directory on their site.